# Detect Application.EnableEvents change

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way (event preferably) to detect if the user has set Application.EnableEvents to false?

I have an C# add-in that uses events like SheetChange to log changes, but if the user set it to false that stops working.

I could poll the Application object for the setting, but that would not detect if it has been disabled and enabled within the polling interval. Ideally (ironically) i'd have an event that tells me the setting has been changed?

Comment: I think I need some more background information. When do you need to know this? When an macro is running or do you want an email sent to you personally when someone changes it on a different computer.

Comment: I see your primary difficulty being with VBA being single threaded. To achieve anything close to real time monitoring, perhaps an external program written in one of the C languages could 'eavesdrop' on the application's message queue.

Comment: Yes it's from an add-in, updated the question

Comment: @gjvdkamp Note that if a user sets `Application.EnableEvents = False` he does this on purpose and he probably knows what he is doing (if not you cannot help him anyway). If you would force it back to  `Application.EnableEvents = True` immediately after it changes to `False` you would destroy all the users own macros, because eg. in some events like `Worksheet_Change` it is absolutely necessary to be able to turn it off.

Comment: When events have been disabled no event procedure can run. Therefore you would need a procedure initiated by the user to check if events are enabled and turn them back on if that procedure determines that they are required.

Comment: @Variatus Not necessarily *"a procedure initiated by the user"*. You could run a timed procedure with `Application.OnTime` as a watchdog (assuming that the initial state of `Application.EnableEvents` is `True` which it should be if Excel is started with the addin).

Comment: @PEH Interesting idea! On second thought, it scares me.

Comment: @Variatus jep, it scares me too ;) While I got this working well as a watchdog to remember users to save every 10 minutes. This will probably easily go crazy if you set it to run every second.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ It's no problem having a application.ontime running in the background. I made a workbook that every two seconds look at what has been copied to the clipboard, if it's "something that needs to be printed", the macro formats the data and prints it to the default printer. This way our staff can just highlight a row in SAP and click CTRL+C and it's printed (given that it's something that should be printed)

Comment: Just to be clear, is your add-in coded in VBA? This is actually fairly easy to do in .NET with [a hooking library](https://easyhook.github.io/).  The linked example uses native dlls with a managed wrapper, so it *might* be possible to use directly from VBA.

Comment: Wow never knew you could do that.. So I could hook into the property, and then still pass the value to the original property but be aware of it? Impressive thanks I'll read up on it

Answer (score 0):

Set a dedicated global variable and assign the value TRUE with the Open event. Then poll the Application.EnableEvents property as you suggest and compare its status with the variable. A change has occurred if the property is different from the value recorded in the variable. You may then take action to realign the variable with the actual.

Comment: While this is good for a watchdog it does not trigger code when you run `Application.EnableEvents = False`